# Define editor template that makes use of ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please help me to implement the editor template when Model and ModelState mismatch.

For example: Model.A == 'x', ViewData.ModelState['A'] == 'y'.

That can occur when form was posted invalid.

Native templates take this in account and display right value from the ModelState. But i could't find their sources.

I need to implement this in my own temlate. Should i just check for a present value in ModelState and use it if it is set. Or may you suggest a better way?

Comment: Make use of the in-built html helper methods which take this into account. What are you trying to render?

Comment: Javascript component that would edit the field. I solved the issue by storing the initial value by Html.HiddenFor method. Previously i stored the value like this <div data-val = @Model.Value> </div>

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the HtmlHelpers (editors) and came up with this. In the example the model/ value is an integer:

```
var value = Model; //value according to the model
var fieldName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("");
ModelState modelState;
if(ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fieldName, out modelState) && modelState.Value != null)
{
    value = (int?) modelState.Value.ConvertTo(typeof(int?), null);
}
```

Now the *value* contains the model value or the posted ModelState value (the *attemptedValue*).